# Can't access camera on API < 23 devices with app having permissions

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I'm developing an android app and i have problems with the camera permission.
On click of a button i call this

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
            } else {
                BarCodeReaderActivity.startActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE_BAR_CODE, mStatus);
            }
        }else{
            if (cameraAvailable)
                BarCodeReaderActivity.startActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE_BAR_CODE, mStatus);
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, KanbanBoxSettings.getInstance(this).getTranslationString(Strings.message_camera_not_available), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
```

When i look on 
`Settings > Apps > "Your app" > Permissions` i see that the app has the camera permission so why is the camera still unavailable?

I don't know if this errorlog is usefull but here is what i get:

> E/StopWatchTimer: [LOG_ERR]StopWatchTimerStart : 63 - StopWatchTimer have already start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method before executing your camera code.

```
public void checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        // You don't have the permission you need to request it
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
    } else {
        // You have the permission.
        setUserLocation();
    }
}
```

Then, Override onRequestPermissionsResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setUserLocation();
        } else {
            toast(getApplicationContext(),"You have cancelled location accessed request");
            currentLoaction.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location));
        }
    }
}
```

Now call your camera method. If this is not working then post your camera calling code.

Comment: what is setUserLocation()?

Comment: That is my method. you will use openCamera() to open the camera

Comment: @DavideBicego Replace permissions to the one which you required.